# Angular: Access is blocked by CORS policy while using HttpClient.request() to upload data to Springboot App

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I'm creating codes to upload file/image to server (spring boot) but everytime I  tried it always blocked by CORS policy.

I'm creating codes to upload file/image to server (spring boot) but everytime I  tried it always blocked by CORS policy.

This is my service

```
pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file', file);

    let hd = new HttpHeaders();
    hd = hd.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://xxxxx:8092');
    hd = hd.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    hd = hd.append('Accept', 'multipart/form-data');

    console.log(hd);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://xxxxx:8092/post', formdata, {
        headers: hd,
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'text'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

And this is my typesript

```
 selectedFiles: FileList;
 currentFileUpload: File;
 progress: { percentage: number } = { percentage: 0 };

 selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
 }

 upload() {
    this.progress.percentage = 0;

    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.accountService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(event => {

    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
       this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
    }
    });

    this.selectedFiles = undefined;
 }
```

Comment: `CORS` errors have very little to do with your code. Check whether the server you're sending the file to actually allows you to (based on CORS headers).

Comment: As @Sébastien pointed its not code problem its server not allowing access to resources ,easiest way is to add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` on top of your post method in RestController.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, @.NenadRadak thanks for answering, I already put CrossOrigin annotation as Nenad said, but still no luck.. Or there any other ways to set that in springboot?

Comment: Putting @crossOrigin(origins="*") on top on restcontroller  if its not working then  add this extn. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: hi, @harkeshkumar. I already used that extension too but still not worked..

Comment: than its should be issue in code ..

Comment: can you please tell me more about what you doing and how  ------- or also share  your code to we can look on it to help you

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
add @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") to your controller method.